# Nodejs WebService database Select

Tags: node.js, database, rest, web-services, class

I am trying to do Nodejs database operations through the class, the route and method I pass through the route reaches the model and the select operation is done.
but when I send the data it is "undefined" in app.use

*Route Code*

```
var Select = require('../models/queryClass');
obj = new Select();
router.use(function (req, res) {
    res.json(obj.Data(req.method, req.path))
});
```

*Model Code*

```
class Select {
    Data(metodh, path) {
        if (metodh == "GET" && path == "/data") {
            db.query("select * from data ", function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return err;
                }
                else {
                    return result
                }
            })
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: where do you send data to app.use?

Comment: I would like to use it on the submitted page, but I get it as undefined.

Comment: put the code where you get undefined...

Comment: when I print it on the screen in the data class, there is data in it but when I press the screen on the "Route Code" side where I return it, I get undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that inside anonymous function the response is comming asynchronously and you never actually return the value outside that function. 
Try to use [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises), which should look something like this:

```
class Select {
    Data(metodh, path) {
        if (metodh == "GET" && path == "/data") {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                db.query("select * from data ", function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(result);
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    }
};
```

And to get the answer you have to use the promise way; **(then - catch)**

```
obj.Data(req.method, req.path)
   .then(result => console.log(result))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Note: I didn't test it, but this way it should work. Before you never actually returned the result since it was async.

Comment: @Coder ok, let me know :)

Comment: You're Welcome! (if it works you can accept the answer)

Comment: sorry. I did not realize.:)